# Build website deployment package as a postbuild event

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, msdeploy

I am using visual studio 2010. I have a website project that I would like to build a website deployment package every time I build a the project. Basically I am looking for some example of a post build MSBuild command that will basically do the same thing as the "Build Deployment Package" option from the right click menu of the website.

Comment: Really what we are trying to do is to package the output from 2 website projects and 2 databaseGeneration projects into one folder. Maybe there is a better way to do this.
Structure<br />
   website1 <br />
      websiteDeployment<br />
      sqlScripts<br />
   website2<br />
      websiteDeployment<br />
      sqlScripts<br />

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you are using Web Application Projects, because Web Site projects do not have the "Build Deployment Package".

**I would recommend not performing a package on every build**, because it will slow down your development drastically. With that being said, you can do it here is how.

If you **really** wanted to do this your best bet is not to use post-build event, but to edit the project file and extend the build process. To do this open the .csproj file for your web and then towards the bottom (*after the Import elements*) place the following

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <BuildDependsOn>
    $(BuildDependsOn);
    Package
  </BuildDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

What this does is extend the build process to call the **Package** target. This is the same target that is called when you invoke the "Build Deployment Package" target in Visual Studio.

Comment: This doesn't work. There is a circular dependency involving target "Build". (Package call Build, Build call Package...)

Comment: error MSB4006: There is a circular dependency in the target dependency graph involving target "Build".

Comment: I've tried on another computer, and it works. So nevermind ^^

Comment: First I got the circular dependency error, but changing Package to CreatePackage solved the problem.

Comment: I got the circular dependency (but only when building from command line, not inside VS).  "CreatePackage" did not work (target does not exist).  In order to get a package as part of every build I changed my DefaultTargets of the Project element to be "Build;Package" which would seem to address Sayed's concern about not packaging during build (from within VS) yet support producing a Package as part of a command line build

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that this will either work in VS builds *or* work with MSBuild, but not both?  Is there any solution that will work for both?

Answer (score 1):

For me, [Sayed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3158986/67824) didn't work with a command-line msbuild execution (I needed the `Publish` target, but the idea is the same):

> There is a circular dependency in the target dependency graph
>   involving target "Build"

I couldn't use `DefaultTargets` because I wanted to publish on the command-line but only build from VS. Here's what did work:

```
<Project 
      ToolsVersion="12.0" 
      DefaultTargets="BuildAndOrPublish" 
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup>
      <BuildAndOrPublishDependsOn Condition=" '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == 'true' ">
        Build
      </BuildAndOrPublishDependsOn>  
      <BuildAndOrPublishDependsOn Condition=" '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' != 'true' ">
        Publish
      </BuildAndOrPublishDependsOn>  
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="BuildAndOrPublish" DependsOnTargets="$(BuildAndOrPublishDependsOn)"/>
```