# Call Publish after Build in MSBuild

Tags: build, msbuild, publish

I am trying to call the Publish target every time I build my WPF app. I have tweaked the .csproj file to include this:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <Message Text="Running AfterBuild..." />
  <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration); PublishDependsOn=" Targets="Publish" />
</Target>
```

When I run this from the command line, I see the message that it is 'Running AfterBuild...' but nothing happens. If I remove the '; PublishDependsOn=' from the `Properties` of the `MSBuild` task, I get a circular reference error.

What magic am I missing here?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158341/build-website-deployment-package-as-a-postbuild-event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I figured out how to do what I want to do. Instead of trying to explicitly call Publish in AfterBuild, I just added it to the `DefaultTargets` of the project. Now it calls Build then Publish.

`<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build;Publish" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">`

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work for me. What project type are you building?May be smth else I'm missing here?