# Visual Studio 2013 Build and Publish

Tags: visual-studio-2013, build, msbuild, publish, msdeploy

I have mixed web and windows projects in VS 2013. I have a solution to build all the projects. For testing purposes I would like to automatically deploy some of the web projects into a local folder. I can do that manually, right click menu and select publish...

I have created publish profile which looks like

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\bin\PublishFolder\</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I can publish from the command line using msbuild as

```
msbuild C:\work\Source\AppManager\SereverManager.csproj  /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Local
```

That gives me the designed outcome as well.

What I would like to do is combine project build and publish. Which means I would like to deploy automatically every time I build the project.

I tried setting a batch file and calling msbuild from post-build event, but that causes VS to freeze, not even sure if that is the right approach. Is it possible to modify my csproj file to publish every time I build the project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is absolutely possible.  Simply add the following XML to your ServerManager.csproj file.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DeployOnBuild>true</DeployOnBuild>
    <PublishProfile>Local</PublishProfile>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

UPDATED: 2017-02-13

After actually testing this solution I found Yusuf was correct and the deployment only worked when I explicitly set the `DeployOnBuild` and `PublishProfile` MSBuild properties on the MSBuild.exe call.

```
>"c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Local
```

Setting properties in the .csproj generally works without issue.  It appears the `DeployOnBuild` property is special. Not sure if this is a bug or intentional but setting it in the project file or a referenced targets file is overwritten somewhere in the build. Only when you define it as a global MSBuild property by setting it as a flag on the MSBuild.exe call is it respected.

Once I discovered this I found an alternate solution that works.  Pass the properties to a second MSBuild call in your project:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <MSBuild Condition="'$(DeployOnBuild)'!='true'" Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)" Properties="DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=Local;BuildingInsideVisualStudio=False"/>
</Target>
```

Now it will automatically deploy whether you build in VS or from the commandline.

Comment: Thanks @chief7 . I tried your suggestion but it didn't get me what I was looking. I even tried adding DeployOnBuild and PublishProfile in the PropertyGroup for Release Configuration

Comment: I've done this many times so I know it works. Are you building the Release configuration?

Comment: Yes I am building Release configuration. I am sure it is doable, just not sure what I am missing. I have created link in the original message to copy of the csproj file.

Comment: I worked around it by making my project work with MSBuild but not VS. Your solution handles both cases and is more elegant.

Comment: Glad it was helpful.  Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

Building on @chief7's answer, I was able to get this working in an MVC project in Visual Studio 2015 like so:

```
<Target Name="Deploy" AfterTargets="Build">
    <MSBuild
        Condition="'$(DeployOnBuild)'!='true'"
        Projects="$(ProjectPath)"
        Targets="WebPublish"
        Properties="PublishProfile=$(AutoDeployPublishProfileName)"/>
</Target>
```

The original answer was throwing `MSB4006` for me:

> There is a circular dependency in the target dependency graph involving target "AfterBuild"

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29480482/1958726) suggested changing the target name and adding the `AfterTargets` property as shown above, which worked.

As an aside for those who need to make deployment contingent on configuration (`Debug`, `Release`, etc.)—@chief7 has [a great write-up on their website](http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2017/03/24/publish-webdeploy-automatically-with-vs-build/).