# How to package and deploy asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, jenkins, deployment, msbuild

I am currently working on automating the build and deploy of an asp.net web application which is developed using vb.net in visual studio. Currently, developers are building the solution and projects using visual studio IDE. In the solution, they have deployment/setup projects (vdproj) for each environment (e.g.: app.setup.dev, app.setup.uat, app.setup.prof) which creates msi for the deployment and the web.config is embedded on it.

We are using github for scm, jenkinsfor build/CI and udeploy for deployment.

I am able to build the solution using msbuild cli thru jenkins. However, vdproj cannot be built using msbuild. Alternatively, I installed Visual Studio and MS VS Installer Projects Extensions in my build server, then build the vdproj using devenv. I am not sure if that is a correct way, maybe it is just a workaround.

What is the appropriate way to package the deployment artifacts (contents files, dlls, web.config) and deploy them? And How? If there’s another way to do it rather than creating MSI, it would be great as I don’t have to get a license for the Visual Studio in my build server.

Answer (score 0):

> I am currently working on automating the build and deploy of an
>   asp.net web application which is developed using vb.net in visual
>   studio.

Maybe you can try publish asp.net web-app by msbuild command-line.

1.As far as I know, we can build and deploy by Visual Studio, see [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/deploying-applications-services-and-components?view=vs-2019).

2.And without VS, you can build and deploy(publish?) by msbuild command-line, there are many resources about this topic.

See:

[How to deploy an ASP.NET MVC application on build using MSBuild in Visual Studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53595614/how-to-deploy-an-asp-net-mvc-application-on-build-using-msbuild-in-visual-studio).

[How to build and deploy a web deployment package using MSBuild](http://blog.chudinov.net/how-to-build-and-deploy-web-deployment-package-using-msbuild/)

[Using MSBuild.exe to “Publish” a ASP.NET MVC 4 project with the cmd line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920146/using-msbuild-exe-to-publish-a-asp-net-mvc-4-project-with-the-cmd-line)

In this way, you can get similar function by specifying the parameters and don't need to have VS installed in the server.

> What is the appropriate way to package the deployment artifacts
>   (contents files, dlls, web.config) and deploy them?

Do you have to package them into .msi or .zip and then publish it. If not, simple msbuild command like: `msbuild xxx.sln /p:WebPublishMethod=xxx /p:PublishProfile=xxx` is enough.

Not certainly sure if it's what you want, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Lance Li-MSFT I'll try your recommendation. Very much appreciated.